# Limit of a function and its derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Do there exist functions $f$, where $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{df(x)}{dx} \neq 0$?

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)$ exists, there is no such function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $f(x)= \frac{1}{x} \sin(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

If *exists* $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}{\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}}=a\ne{0}$ then $\forall \varepsilon>0\;\;\exists x_\varepsilon\colon \;\; \forall {x>x_\varepsilon}$
$$a-\varepsilon<{\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}}<a+\varepsilon, \tag{*}$$
which contradicts the mean value (Lagrange's) theorem.
Therefore if $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}{\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}}$ exists, it equals $0.$

**Edited (more than 8 years later)**

At first it should be said that the claim about contradiction with MVT in the previous answer was formulated insufficiently correctly.
More precizely, it means that the existence of nonzero limit $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}{f'(x)}$ using the Mean Value Theorem contradicts to the fact that the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = 0.$

Note that $({*})$ holds, in particular, for $\varepsilon < \frac{|a|}{2}.$
Now we take an arbitrary $x_1 > x_{\varepsilon}$ and set $x_2 = 2x_{1}.$ Then by the Mean Value Theorem there exists some $\xi, \  x_1 < \xi < x_2,$ such that
$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = f'(\xi)(x_2 - x_1) =  f'(\xi) \cdot x_1. $$Now it follows that $$\left\vert f(x_2) - f(x_1) \right\vert =  \left\vert f'(\xi) \right\vert \cdot x_1 > x_1 \cdot \min\{ |a-\varepsilon|, \   |a+\varepsilon|\}  $$ which is unbounded for sufficiently large $x_1,$ hence $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) $ cannot be $0.$

Comment: Sorry I know it is a very old answer, but I was going to do a question in order to prove that if a function goes to zero then the limit of the derivative, if it exists, is zero, and I have read your answer. I have not understood why the inequality above contradicts the mean value theorem. Would you be so kind to explain it to me?

Comment: @willie: I add some clarification to my previous answer.

Comment: @ M. Strochyk Thanks a lot!